# Regex Rules for Google Analytics Funnels

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So been digging about and made some absolute messes but can't seem to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to set up a number of steps to identify at which stage users drop off so thereby creating a funnel towards the final goal.

So step 1 is being on the home page

Step 2 is being on a top level category such as /TOP-TIER
There is no forward slash at the end of a category so essentially I would like any visit to a page with no more than 1 forward slash present, this excluding any mention of "checkout/cart", "customer/account, or ".html""

Step 3 is looking for a subcategory page e.g.  /TOP-TIER/SECONDARY-TIER
Same gig as before, no mention of checkout or account or html but this time the qualifying factor is at least 2 forward slashes

Step 4 is the product which I've got and step 5 is some sort of action.

It is step 2 and 3 I need help with. I did attempt:  /.*[^/]  for the second step but very much doubting I got that right.

- Step 1:Home: `^/$`
- Step 2:Top-Tier:
- Step 3:Secondary-Tier:
- Step 4:Product: `^(.*)html$`
- Step 5:Goal: `/checkout/cart/(.*)|/customer/account/(.*)|/giftindex/(.*)`

Much appreciate everyone!

Comment: Try 2) `/[^/]+`, 3) `/[^/]+/[^/]+`

Comment: For 2, this got the same figure as I previously had so that's encouraging. Thanks for that, looks far tidier. As for 3 it seems to work but would you mind explaining how that actually functions so that I can understand for next time? Thanks a lot Wiktor

Comment: Well, I am not sure what exact input you will have. Perhaps, you will need `^` and `$` to enclose my suggested patterns for them to work correctly for you. `/[^/]+` matches a `/` and then 1 or more characters other than `/`. If you add `^` at the beginning, it will only match at the start of the string. `$` anchors the match at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, it was the /[^/]+ which was throwing me. Very useful to know, thanks

Comment: So, is that working for you? Shall I post as an answer?

Comment: I've made some tweaks for the user cases so correct me if I'm wrong: ^/[^/|checkout/|customer/|giftindex/]+ with start with / and then match one or more character other than / or checkout/ or customer/ or giftindex/. Is that correct?

Comment: You *are* wrong, just read what you wrote: *one or more character other than ... `checkout/`*. The `checkout/` is not a character, but a *sequence of characters*. There is no way in RE2 to match sequences other than predefined sequences as RE2 does not support *lookarounds*. You need to set up several filters, or set specific options in your filter to make it "negate" the regex.